# Include path not working for Bluez libraries

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, bluez

Im trying to develop application in C using Bluez library on linux. I cant figure out how to properly pass
all include paths to compiler so that all libraries I need will be visible.

No matter what I try I get following errors:

```
cc -g -I<PATH_TO_BLUEZ>/bluez-5.54/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include/ -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/ -ldbus-1 -ldbus-glib-1     -c -o disc_gdbus.o disc_gdbus.c
cc -o myprog disc_gdbus.o -I<PATH_TO_BLUEZ>/bluez-5.54/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include/ -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/ -ldbus-1 -ldbus-glib-1 
disc_gdbus.o: In function `print_chrc':
<PATH_TO_APP>/disc_gdbus.c:98: undefined reference to `bt_uuidstr_to_str'
disc_gdbus.o: In function `print_desc':
<PATH_TO_APP>/disc_gdbus.c:120: undefined reference to `bt_uuidstr_to_str'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'myprog' failed
make: *** [myprog] Error 1
```

I need to include following files:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include "src/shared/util.h"
#include "src/shared/queue.h"
#include "src/shared/io.h"
#include "src/shared/shell.h"
#include "gdbus/gdbus.h"
```

Function bt_uuidstr_to_str is in directory `<PATH_TO_BLUEZ>/bluez-5.54/src/shared/util.h`. So it should be seen.

In the makefile I include everything like this:

```
INC=-I<PATH_TO_BLUEZ>/bluez-5.54/ \
    -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 \
    -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 \
    -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include/ \
    -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/ \
    -ldbus-1 \
    -ldbus-glib-1 \

src = disc_gdbus.c
obj = $(src:.c=.o)

CFLAGS=-g $(INC) $(LIBS)

myprog: $(obj)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(obj) myprog
```

I studied ways to modify include path, and this method should allow linker to see all relevant files, but somehow it does not.
I supplied those include paths to VS Code and they worked without problems:

```
{
"C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
    "<PATH_TO_BLUEZ>/bluez-5.54/**",
    "/usr/include/glib-2.0"
    ],
}
```

Which leaves me even more puzzled. I spent already multiple hours on this and I have no idea why those includes do not work.

Comment: That's not an include problem, It is a linking problem. Where exactly is `<PATH_TO_BLUEZ>`? If it is not a standard library location you need to pass in `-L` to tell the linker where the bluez libraries are located.

Comment: `<PATH_TO_BLUEZ>` is in my home/documents directory, so not standard one. I see no .so or .a files in this directory do I don't have a clue how to make this work... Simply adding -L flag instead of -I does not change the outcome

Comment: Did you actually build `bluez`?

Comment: Generally one gets these paths using `pkg-config`.  Your build should contain a `.pc` file which you should use with it to get the proper arguments for compiling and linking.

Comment: pkg-config might be indeed a better way to solve this. While `pkg-config --modversion bluez` outputs correctly with my bluez's version, when I include `pkg-config --cflags --libs bluez` it still won't let me use `#include "src/shared/util.h"`. I feel like I'm close, but something is still missing in my configuration... which is extremely frustrating